# Which time server is used by Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, time

What is the URL of the timer server used by Ubuntu?

The settings page just shows the radio option "Automatically from Internet", but it does not show the actual server URL, like in WIndows.

[image]

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/391097/32239

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, `ntp.ubuntu.com`. This is supported by example preseed files and the value used by the server and network installation methods (for which, the debug output shows `ntp.ubuntu.com` as the value for the NTP server). To check the server status and time, you can run `ntpdate` in debug mode (to see if there are other problems), or in query mode (to just see the time):

```
ntpdate -d ntp.ubuntu.com # Debug mode
ntpdate -q ntp.ubuntu.com # Query mode
```

Comment: Is there a way to actually see the time on the server other than looking at my OS clock. The address does not return anything in a browser so i am guessing the browser cannot understand the NTP protocol.

Comment: @faizal The time on the server? You can run the `ntpdate` command in debug mode: `ntpdate -d ntp.ubuntu.com`. Or in query mode: `ntpdate -q ntp.ubuntu.com`.

Answer (score 7):

Your system will use Ubuntu's NTP server at `ntp.ubuntu.com` by default.

To find what NTP server is being used, run:

```
grep ^server /etc/ntp.conf
```

If you get an error, then NTP is not installed.  To install it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

[image]

Comment: I get `grep: /etc/ntp.conf: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

ntpdate is deprecated. You can use this command to get the status and see which server is being used:

```
systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
```

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in [SaTa's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1128600/8822), this is now managed by systemd, with the `systemd-timesyncd` service.

The configuration is in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`.

Use the `timedatectl` command and it's variations with arguments to see all the info. For example:

```
timedatectl
timedatectl timesync-status
timedatectl show-timesync
```

The last 2 examples will show which NTP server is used.