# How to change the time server for the _in built_ internet time in ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, settings, time, ntp

I know there are instructions for installing full NTP, but I'd rather change the default server under the default implementation. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391089/how-to-change-the-time-server-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts-without-installing-the-ntp-p) has come up before for 12.04 LTS, however the answer there:

> edit the value of NTPSERVERS in /etc/default/ntpdate

appears to be no longer valid.

Comment: In my `/etc/default/ntpdate` there is a warning that the file is not actually used, but that `/etc/ntp.conf` is used instead. There are various time servers mentioned in `/etc/ntp.conf`, did you try changing that?

Comment: what was the question before 12.04 ?

Comment: @Jos: neither of those exist for me on a fresh install of 16.04 LTS (installed in VMware player.)

Comment: @Anwar: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/391089/how-to-change-the-time-server-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts-without-installing-the-ntp-p)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the official documentation at:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html

> The nameserver to fetch time for timedatectl and timesyncd from can be specified in /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf and with flexible additional config files in /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf.d/.

Comment: Cheers :). I like to be thorough and check that these changes are actually taking place, the man pages for timesyncd gave me the command "systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service" as an example; and that showed up the NTP server I'd assigned.

Answer (score 13):

Ubuntu 16.04 uses by default server `ntp.ubuntu.com` [[reference](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp)].

To change the default server, edit the config file with an editor:

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
```

Uncomment the `NPT=` line and define the server you want to be used *instead of* default:

```
[Time]
NTP=some.ntp.server.com
```

To "audit" the time-synchronization events and verify the server that was contacted, use the following command:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep systemd-timesyncd
```

Comment: `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` can also be used to "audit," see PaulBags comment on the accepted answer (I like yours better).  And `sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd` can be used to force a sync.

Comment: Are ypou sure that this is proper way? Are you surethat config will be not ovverride after systemd-upgrade? Maybe better create conf file under `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf.d/ntp.conf` ?

Comment: Would recommend using `journalctl -fu systemd-timesyncd.service` to view updates in real time to the time service. Or at least do a `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, `cat` does not update.